# How to implement a Non scrollable listview inside a SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to implement a non scrollable ListView builder here but can't seem to find how to do it. Reason is because i want everything to be scrollable and i dont want to have a Scrollable widget inside a scrollable parent.

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Bar Here')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Hello World'),
              Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                color: Color(0xffaaaaaa),
                                height: 20,
                                child: Text('Jss One')),
                            Text(
                              'English',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 50,
                ),
              ),],),));
  }}
```

Comment: i did, but what i am going for is to display all the data in a non scrollable widget. i have a parent widget that is SingleChildScrollView and i want all the contents to be scrollable, not just the listView Widget itself

Comment: so use `CustomScrollView` like: `child: DefaultTextStyle.merge(
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
child: CustomScrollView(
slivers: <Widget>[
SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text('header'),),
SliverList(
delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((ctx, index) {
print(index);
return Text('item #$index');
},
childCount: 50,
)),
SliverToBoxAdapter(child: Text('footer'),),
],
),
),
`

Comment: I did it this way, and it worked too. This is simpler than what i did. Thank you @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Bar Here')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Hello World'),
              Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() //add this line,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                color: Color(0xffaaaaaa),
                                height: 20,
                                child: Text('Jss One')),
                            Text(
                              'English',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 50,
                ),
              ),],),));
  }}
```

set physics property to NeverScrollablePhysics() in order to not scroll the lisview

Comment: its NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

Comment: Thank you by the way. It works the way i want it to

Comment: Oh yes, NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() :)

Answer (score 1):

try using physics property of `listview`

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

hope it helps..

Comment: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() 

not

NeverScrollablePhysics()

And yes it works

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to what i was going for.
What happens here is the ListBuilder widget will build a List of items not in a Scrollable widget. The parent widget itself is scrollable which makes the whole Screen scrollable. To do this, add `shrinkWrap: true` and `physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to the `ListView.builder()` property.

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('App Bar Here')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Hello World'),
              Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true, //add this line
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() //add this line,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                                color: Color(0xffaaaaaa),
                                height: 20,
                                child: Text('Jss One')),
                            Text(
                              'English',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: 50,
                ),
              ),],),));
  }}
```

Comment: this is a wrong way: if you do that `ListView.builder` is useless as it builds all 50 items at once - you can see it if you add `print(index);` before `return Card(...`

Comment: so why dont you use `CustomScrollView` or just a `ListView.builder`(without `SingleChildScrollView`)  that builds all your widgets (including top `Text('Hello World')`)?

Comment: The list is not the only thing on the screen, there are items Above and Below the List. That's why...

Comment: lemme try this way now